# Why i upgrade extensions (at Magento Connect Manager) and "Magento Installation Wizzard" is now forced show. How can i fix it?

Tags: upgrade, local.xml, magento-connect-manager

i just have a problem with an extension upgrade.

I have upgrade some extensions, all to stable version, but then the site is down, and it force me to be redirect to the Magento Installation Wizard!

I try to backup the /app/etc/local.xml file, but its not working. I delete the file ones, the site goes white. Then restore file, and site was back again to the installation wizard.

All files at the FTP are there, and look good. PLEASE HELP!
THANKS!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that I would do is delete  /var/cache and /var/session and try again.
Also if there is not local.xml file Magento will always redirect you to installation because it assumes it is not installed. If it is there check if the nodes are not corrupted in some way, or the permissions are correct (644 is enough).
Check if a file 'maintenance.flag' exists and delete it, that might solve the problem also. Restart your server and php5-fpm.
I hope that helps